# Problem with flash positioning itself over a javascript lightwindow in IE6 & IE7

Tags: javascript, flash, internet-explorer

I have a problem with a flash object placing itself on top over everything in IE6 and IE7.

Firefox renders the page correctly.

I bet somebody else has had this problem and found some kinda solution to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because Flash runs inside an ActiveX control in IE browsers, it doens't follow the stack rules since ActiveX controls are always rendered on to of normal HTML content (except for drop down, annoyingly).

There is a workaround though to force Flash to obey, set the wmode="transparent" in your object tag, and optionally the embedded tag too.

Comment: Worked perfectly when i added a 
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>

Answer (score 0):

[wmode=transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wmode+transparent) is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had a problem with flash menu over the lightwindow panel, and adding wmode="transparent" in the object and embed tags worked.